# Turning codepen JS code into Angular 12 Component

Tags: angular, codepen

I am trying to turn this codepen: https://codepen.io/salihDemircan/pen/QpXvwO into an Angular 12 Component. However, I have difficulty in adjusting the javascript code in order to add it in the `component.ts` file.

I know, that one can use `@ViewChild` for referencing an element, and I am looking for a solution towards this direction. However, it is not evident to me how I could implement it. I would really appreciate a little help here.

Answer (score 1):

copy the file in your `assets` folder. Then on your `Angular.json` file, add the script file on your ``scripts``` like such:

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/your-JS-file"
            ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I was already aware of this solution. What I am looking for, is a more angular-ish way, adjusting the code so as to include it in the `component.ts` file.

Comment: You can just create a function and paste the code and include the function on ```ngOnInit``` function. I've tested it and it works. You just need to import jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. I tried it and it worked.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'; 
...

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.codePen()  //important
  }

codePen(){
    //the JavaScript CodePen code goes here
}
```